# If $H<G$ is of finite index, and for some $x\in G$, $xHx^{-1}\subset H$, prove that $xHx^{-1}=H$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

The original question had 2 parts:

> a. If $H<G$ is finite, and for some $x\in G$, $xHx^{-1}\subset H$, prove that $xHx^{-1}=H$
>
> b. If $H<G$ is of finite index, and for some $x\in G$, $xHx^{-1}\subset H$, prove that $xHx^{-1}=H$

Now I was able to solve part (a) by finding an injection from $H$ to $xHx^{-1}$, but the same approach doesn't seem to work in (b). There also seems to be a lot of (duplicate) questions here about the status without the limitation on $H$, but none of the responses seem to help me in my case.

How is the finite index of $H$ supposed to affect my thinking?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: If $xHx^{-1}\subseteq H$ then show $x^{k+1}Hx^{-k-1} \subseteq x^{k}Hx^{-k}$ for all natural numbers $k$. If $H$ has finite index in $G$, then for some $m$, $x^m\in H.$

Comment: Why does the second statement, about $x^m$ being in $H$ for some $m$, follow from the finite index of $H$?

Comment: Consider the cosets $x^mH$ where $m$ varies over the natural number. There must be finitely many distinct such cosets (by finite index,) so ... @Nescio

Comment: I see.. Thanks!